# What is the best way to update a 100 million rows partitioned table

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We have a table with 100 million records. It’s monthly partitioned on a date column. Now the requirement is to add date parts of that date column. Date,year,month and weeks etc.
for that I need to update the table for existing rows.
What is the best approach to do that? We cannot do no logging in production as the db is set with logging.

Comment: If these new columns are completely defined by your existing column, can you make them virtual columns?

Comment: Why do you not simply update it? How is it possible to add "weeks" to a `DATE` column?

Comment: @eaolson thanks for the reply. This table has only insets and no updates. For new data we can load from source. For existing data or old data, we need to update from the existing column. Aren’t virtual columns gets recalculated every time the column is accessed in the query?  As the data is constant I don't see the need for virtual column here.

Comment: @Xyz You are trading calculating the values (but only when they are needed) with virtual columns for increasing the size of the rows with materialized columns which will mean that there is more IO.

Answer (score 1):

Make the columns virtual and derive them from your existing date column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value DATE);

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (
  year          NUMBER(4,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM value)),
  month         NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM value)),
  day           NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(DAY   FROM value)),
  year_month    DATE        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRUNC(value, 'MM')),
  dt            DATE        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRUNC(value)),
  iso_year_week VARCHAR2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(value, 'IYYY-IW'))
);
```

Then, if you have the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (SYSDATE);
```

The table contains the columns:

> | VALUE | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | YEAR_MONTH | DT | ISO_YEAR_WEEK |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-06-26 11:14:13 | 2022 | 6 | 26 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-26 00:00:00 | 2022-25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dc317fe65f8d417d43761121ae2b1e36)*